# Android searchview wait until user stops typing before query

Tags: android, autocomplete, simplecursoradapter, searchview

I am implementing a SearchView with a cursor adapter attached as SuggestionAdapter.I want to wait until the user stops typing before executing an expensive filter of a SearchView.But any change to searchview, runQuery method in filterprovider is getting called immediately.

```
cAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    //my code
        });
```

There is a setDelayer() method in Filter class but it is not accessible.
How can we accomplish this?

Comment: Have you implemented `Filterable` in your class?